# How to send email through programetically in magento 2.0?

Tags: magento2, customer, email, email-templates, customer-account

I am sending conformation email while creating new account to the customer using   **$customer->sendNewAccountEmail();** in controller it is working fine,
but i am trying for  at a same time, When I want to send another email with another email template to other customer which are already registered,
so that's  why i want to know about send email through Programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

I am using this code for sending email.

```
namespace [Vender]\[Extension]\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Sendmail extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_ADMIN_QUOTE_SENDER = 'Email Sender';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_ADMIN_QUOTE_NOTIFICATION = 'Your Template Path';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_ADMIN_NAME = 'Sender Name';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_ADMIN_EMAIL = 'Receiver Email';

    protected $inlineTranslation;
    protected $transportBuilder;
    protected $_logLoggerInterface;

    public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
    TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
    LoggerInterface $logLoggerInterface,
    array $data = [])
    {
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->_logLoggerInterface = $logLoggerInterface;
        parent::__construct($context,$data);
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        try
        {

            // Send Mail
            $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder
               ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_ADMIN_QUOTE_NOTIFICATION, $storeScope))
               ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => 'frontend',
                        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                    ]
                )
               ->setTemplateVars([
                    'var1'  => 'Value',
                    'var2'  => 'Value'
                ])
               ->setFrom($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_ADMIN_QUOTE_SENDER, $storeScope))
               ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_ADMIN_EMAIL, $storeScope))
               ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        } catch(\Exception $e){
            $this->_logLoggerInterface->debug($e->getMessage());
            exit;   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any answer, I also looking for a similar question. And are you sure above coding is working fine ?

Comment: I am already used this code in my one extension, It working fine. You need to just replaces your template, Variables, Sender and Receivers of email.

Comment: I'm new to M2, please could you explain what should be 'Your Template Path'

Comment: Template path means your custom template path which you want to send while your email send. In your extension you create one html file for email template, that file path you need to specify here.

Comment: Can you tell me how can attach  pdf file in email

Comment: @ShownakShah you need to attch pdf file as email attchment, right?

Comment: Yes @Dhiren i am going through it but not working,  $pdfFile = 'abc\def\view\adminhtml\pdf\pdf-sample.pdf';  ->addAttachment(file_get_contents($pdfFile)); //Attachment goes here.

Comment: @ShownakShah is that any error in log file?

Comment: @Dhiren Issue Solved after using this   $pdfFile = 'file:///home/shah/workspace/magento2/app/code/Abc/Def/view/adminhtml/pdf/pdf-sample.pdf';    Thank You...

Comment: I'm getting this error:Undefined property: ****\*****\Controller\Index\Sendmail\Interceptor::$scopeConfig in /data/web/magento2/app/code/****/****/Controller/Index/Sendmail.php on line 45

Comment: I get an error : Fatal error: Call to a member function setTemplateOptions() on null in /home/magento/public_html/project/app/code/Namespace/Module/Controller/Chat/Chat.php on line 96

Comment: verify your email template path and othe variable.